# How can I create a slider on an iPad or iPhone web aplication?

Tags: javascript, ipad

I have tried making a slider using the ontouchstart, ontouchmove, and ontouchend built in funcionts. the slider works only if the user slides the finger 100% horizontally and that is not always the case. How can I create a slider on an iPad or iPhone web application?